# Python 'sounddevice' library - disable audio output

Tags: python

This script checks sound level and visualizes it on the terminal. My only problem is that the script outputs the stream to the assigned audio output (HDMI or headphone jack). With the microphone on, it can create feedback. I could turn the volume down but I wonder if I can disable the audio output at all?

```
import sounddevice as sd
from numpy import linalg as LA
import numpy as np

duration = 10  # seconds

def print_sound(indata, outdata, frames, time, status):
    volume_norm = np.linalg.norm(indata)*10
    print (int(volume_norm))

with sd.Stream(callback=print_sound):
    sd.sleep(duration * 1000)
```